# Relation between two JSONs through keys

Tags: json, vue.js, key

So I have 2 different JSONs.
Books

```
{
  "books": [{
    "name": "Lord of the rings",
    "author": 1,
    "year": 1937,
    "genre": 3,
    "imageUrl": "https://cdn.lifehack.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/9780618640157_custom-s6-c30.jpg",
    "availability": true
  }]
}
```

and, the other one, Authors

```
{
  "authors": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "J.R.R. Tolkien"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Harper Lee"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "J.K. Rowling"
  }]
}
```

I want to have the author like an id, so when I'll display the author for the a book, I want the name(that's in the second json), not the id.
How can I do that?
Not sure if matters, but I'm working in VUE.

Answer (score 0):

You could use loash's find method to do this e.g.

Documentation: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find

```
_.find(authors, { 'id': 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the native Array.filter method, like so:

```
let tolkien = authors.filter(author => !!author.id === 1)
```

Using .filter means you don't need to include a library like lodash just for this one method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object with keys mapped to authors (i.e `author[1] = {id: 1, ...}`) which will let you quickly and easily access any author by his/her id. Example:

```
let authorByIds = {};
authors.forEach(author => {
    authorByIds[author.id] = {...author};
});

let firstBook = books[0];

console.log(authorByIds[firstBook.author]);
// will output author with id = 1, i.e J.R.R. Tolkien
```